# What is the difference between linking and using a header file?

Tags: c, compilation, linker

For example, what is the difference between linking two files

```
gcc -c func.c 
gcc -c main.c 
gcc func.o main.o -o main
```

and using a header file

```
#include func.h

int main{
....
.. 
}
```

if they seem to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: They don't accomplish the "same thing". One is a build process, the other is the preparation of a translation unit submitted to that build process. Your first example has two translation units (think: compiled "things"). Your second is just the source behind one of those compiled "things", and includes a preprocessor instruction to injest an external header file while preparing the source for later compilation.

Comment: `func.h` is not `func.c`.   They serve different purposes.

Comment: @WhozCraig by "same thing" I meant that both ways allow the programmer to use the functions in the func file.

Comment: You do both of these things at once to use the functions in func.c from main.c

Answer (score 6):

They don't "accomplish the same thing".  They accomplish complementary parts of the same thing.  Typically you have to do both: doing just one, or just the other, is totally insufficient.

Here's an imperfect analogy: Suppose you want an addition on your house.  At the start of the project, you sign your name on a contract with the builder, specifying the size and finish of the addition.  At the end of the project, you sign your name on a check to pay the builder for his work.  What's the difference between signing the contract and signing the check?  Why do you have to do both, if they both do the same thing, namely getting you your new addition?

Including a header is (sort of) like signing a contract.  When you say `#include <math.h>`, you're saying "Hey, compiler, there are some math  functions.  Like `sqrt()`, which accepts a `double` and returns a `double`. So if I write `int x = sqrt(144)`, make sure you do a conversion from `int` to `double` before passing the number to `sqrt`, and make sure you do a conversion from `double` back to `int` before assigning the result to `x`."

Linking against a library is (sort of) like paying your bill.  (Actually, if I'm honest, it's almost nothing like paying a bill, but bear with me.)  When you put `-lm` at the end of the command line, you're saying "Hey, compiler, those math functions we agreed on, the ones whose details are specified in the contract called `<math.h>`, the ones I've been calling, now I'm paying up, here's where those functions actually *are*."

Comment: Using your analogy, if both methods eventually result in an "addition on your house" in what situations would I use a header file instead of linking against a library

Comment: @cprogrammer100 If you sign a contract but don't pay, you get sued.  If you skip the contract, then when the time comes to pay, you may find that what got built wasn't what you wanted.  When it comes to programming, if you include the header but don't link against the library, you get error messages like "Undefined external: `_sqrt`".  If you skip the header but link against the library, you get wrong answer, because the compiler doesn't know to insert those int/double conversions when you called `sqrt`.  In general, you have to do *both*.

Comment: @cprogrammer100 If you had a header file which contained only declarations of things *other* than external functions -- perhaps it had only `struct` declarations and preprocessor `#define`s -- it would be fine and meaningful to include that header even though you didn't link a corresponding library.  And theoretically it might be possible to have a library full of functions which it was possible to call correctly without having included a corresponding header file, although in practice I would expect this to be exceedingly rare.

Answer (score 3):

`#include` makes all the source code in the included file available to the compiler, effectively including it as part of the file being compiled. This is commonly used to declare names that are defined in other files. That tells the compiler what types of the named objects and functions are, and the compiler can use this to generate code that **uses** those objects and functions. But the code does not actually contain definitions for those objects and functions.

When files are linked together, the link takes objects and functions from multiple files and builds them together into one executable program (or into a library or object module for further linking later). While putting these objects and functions together, the linker **resolves** references to objects and functions.

Suppose the `main` function file main.c calls function `foo` in file function.c. The header function.h will declare `foo`, which tells the compiler what arguments the function requires and what type of value it returns. When compiling main.c, the compiler will produce an object module main.o that contains a **call** to `foo`. Inside the object file, `foo` is represented only by its name. When compiling function.c, the compiler will produce an object module function.o that contains the actual function `foo`.

When the linker builds the executable, it will decide where the function `foo` will be placed inside the program. Then, it will go into the code for `main` where the call instruction is and modify the address or offset used in the call instruction so that it points to the `foo` function. Then, in the executable program file, the call to `foo` contains only an address or offset; it is no longer referred to by name. The different calls and definitions in the program have been linked together.

Including headers is used to tell the compiler about types of objects and functions. The objects and functions remain in separate files, each in the object file corresponding to the source file in which it is defined.

Linking is used to combine the different object modules into one executable program file.

Comment: So if both methods allow you to access functions outside your main file, When would I make my func file a .h file instead of making it a .c file and linking it with main.c?

Comment: You need both: The compiler needs the **declaration** of the external function to generate the correct code (and to give you meaningful messages if you did something wrong). The executable needs the **implementation** (aka definition) of the external function so that it can be executed. So the approved style is to provide "func.h" for inclusion in the using module and "func.c" for the implementation.

Comment: Oh, and please don't put the **definition** of variables and/or functions in a header file. That is, nearly always; there are corner cases that do this.